# Why is my Node.js api recognising a duplicate user from MongoDb but still adding an additional user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have included `unique: true` property for email while declaring the schema for user.

I am also using the `mongoose.model.findOne(query, options)` method of mongoose to check if user already exists and it throws the expected "User already exists" response in case of a duplicate email.

However, the user gets added to the DB anyway.

Below is the code for my API:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoUri = require('../../config/db.json').mongoUri;

const UserModel = require('../../models/user.js');

const options = {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
 useCreateIndex: true,
 useFindAndModify: false,
 autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
 poolSize: 5, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
 serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Keep trying to send operations for 5 seconds
 socketTimeoutMS: 5000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
 family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
};

//@route    POST api/user
//@desc     Create User
//@access   private

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
 const {
  email,
  name,
  password,
  permission
 } = req.body;
 try {
  
    mongoose.connect(mongoUri, options);
  
    var query = UserModel.where({
   email: email
  });

  query.findOne((err, existingUser) => {
   if (err) {
    return res.status(422).send(err);
   }
   if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(422).send({
     error: 'User already exists.'
    });
   }
  });
    
  const user = new UserModel({
   name,
   email,
   password,
   permission
  })
    
  const newUser = await user.save();
  return res.status(200).send(newUser);

 } catch (error) {
  return res.status(503).send(error);
 }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I am not able to figure out the solution using the documentation and I am unable to find a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is as you create the newUser outside of an asynchronous block of code, so both of them will be executed, the check and creating a new user

so creating a new user does not wait until the email check is done

I suggest you to move creating the new user operation to be inside the call back of the email check

something like that

```
var query = UserModel.where({
    email: email
});

query.findOne((err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err);
    }
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(422).send({
            error: 'User already exists.'
        });
    } else {
        // in the else condition, the email does not exist before in db, then create the user
        const user = new UserModel({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            permission
        })

        const newUser = await user.save();
        return res.status(200).send(newUser);
    }
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

````
    let userData = req.body;
    Employee.findOne({ email: req.body.email}, (error, user) =>{
      if(error){
        console.log(error)
      }
      else if(!user) {
        let newEmployee = new Employee(userData);

    newEmployee.save(function(err, employees) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({status: false, data: 'Unable to add!'});
        }

        res.json({status: true, data: employees});
    });
}

    else {
        console.log("Email Already exists")
      }
    
})
};```
````